# Tkinter not showing DB number in Label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I need to fetch one number from a column

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT vacas FROM animales''')
cantidad1 = cursor.fetchone()
```

Then I need this number to be shown in a Tkinter Label:

```
cantidad = Label (ventana, textvariable=cantidad1).grid(row=1, column=3)
```

And I have a refresh button in order to update the data.

```
ref = Button (ventana, text="Refresh", command=update )
```

The problem is that the Label is always blank, even when I press button and call Update():

Here is the complete code:

```
cantidad1 = 0 
ventana = Tk()
cursor = db.cursor()

def update():
    cursor.execute('''SELECT vacas FROM animales''')
    cantidad1 = cursor.fetchone()
    print (cantidad1[0]) #The number shown in command is right, but blank in tkinter.




ref = Button (ventana, text="Refresh", command=update )
ref.grid(row=3, column=2)
cantidad = Label (ventana, textvariable=cantidad1).grid(row=1, column=3)


ventana.mainloop()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aft0y.jpg "Screenshot tkinter blank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `textvariable` in Tkinter can be handy, but it requires thinking a bit in Tcl/Tk style instead of Python style. You may want to read up on it I'm not sure where the best docs are, but [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#patterns) and [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) in the old book are probably a good place to start.

Anyway, a `textvariable` binding has to refer to a Tcl variable, like a `StringVar`. Somewhere before creating that `Label` with `textvariable=cantidad1` you need to do something like this:

```
cantidad1 = StringVar('0')
```

And then, instead of this:

```
cantidad1 = cursor.fetchone()
```

… you have to do this:

```
cantidad1.set(cursor.fetchone())
```

What you're doing is changing the name `cantidad1` to refer to the new result, but what you *need* to do is leave it referring to the `StringVar` and change the value of the `StringVar`, so `Tk` can see it and update the label.

---

While we're at it, I think you actually want something like `cursor.fetchone()[0]`; otherwise you're trying to use a row (probably a `list` or other sequence, not a string).

---

Finally, you could use an `IntVar` here. That would allow you to initialize it to `0` instead of `'0'`, but then of course you have to `set` it to `int(spam)` instead of just `spam`, and you may need some error handling to deal with what happens if the database returns Null.

---

If all of this is Greek to you (or, worse, Tcl), the other option is to just not use Tk variables:

```
cantidad = Label(ventana, text='0').grid(row=1, column=3)
```

Notice that the difference here is that I set the initial `text`, rather than setting a `textvariable`.

So now, every time you fetch new data, you'll have to manually update (re-`config`) the label's text, like this:

```
cantidad1 = ... # code that just gets a normal Python string
cantidad.config(text=cantidad1)
```

This is much less idiomatic Tk code, and arguably less idiomatic Tkinter code—but it's a lot more Pythonic, so it may be easier for you to read/debug/write. (Notice that the first line is exactly what you instinctively wrote, which was wrong with your original design, hence your question, but would be right with the explicit-update design.)

—-

There are other problems in the code that I haven’t fixed. For example, the `grid` method on widgets doesn’t return the widget, it returns `None`. You’re doing it right for `ref`, but not for `cantidad`. Your original code never actually referred to `cantidad`, so that wasn't a problem, but if you, e.g., switch to using manual updates instead of automatic variables, you're going to get a confusing exception about calling `configure` on `None`.

Comment: I'm completely new at this. Cantidad1 is supposed to be a simple number. How is cantidad1.set(...) used?

Comment: @GastonRaboy I rewrote the answer to explain a bit more, but you're probably going to want to find a good tutorial on Tkinter variables. The sections I linked to in the effbot TKinter book should help, but that book is way out of date—written for Python 2.3 or so, and refers to Tcl/Tk docs that are no longer there, and so on. Hopefully there's a better resource for learning, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @GastonRaboy: Alternatively, leave it as "a simple number", and just don't use `textvariable`; instead, write code to explicitly update the label's text every time you fetch new data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I firstly solved the problem using cantidad1.set(cursor.fetchone())
And defining cantidad1 as StringVar. I will be reading your links. Thanks again!

Comment: One needs to configure a label's text option in order to display a letters or numbers. You should probably be simply reconfiguring the label after each query, `label.config(text=cantidad1)` or `label['text'] = cantidad1`.

Comment: In your final code example, `cantidad` will be set to `None`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Good point. I didn’t change any of the other problems from the original code, just the one he was asking about, but it’s worth pointing out.

Comment: @Nae I don’t understand your comment. Calling `configure` after each query is what I suggested in the last (now next-to-last) paragraph. But it isn’t true that you _have to_ do it that way. You can use a `textvariable` as the OP is trying to do, he just needs to get a couple details right. And, since that’s what he was trying and what he was asking about, I put that first.

Comment: @abarnert While it's true that, one doesn't need to configure a widget's text option, however, a widget's text _has_ to be configured in order to display the desired text, be it automatic or manual. Using variable classes are a bit redundant in the case above, that's why I suggested `configure`. You're suggesting the use, but _not_ showing how. The line most relevant creates a new label on top of another with the text value of a 'constant' `'0'`. I disagree that this is clear enough for everyone of what you're suggesting, if not misleading, hence the comment.

Comment: @Nae: The line you're referring to is how the OP's original code creates the label in the first place, just with the `textvariable` replaced by `text`. So I don't think there's any danger that he'd mistake it for being how you update a widget rather than how you create one, or that he'd call it multiple times instead of just once. I'll add an example showing how you'd do the update, but I think it risks diverting attention from the main part of the answer, which is about making `textvariable` work properly.

Comment: @abarnert You must have meant `config` or `configure` instead of `update`, which by default only takes the object it is a method of as the argument. Also, it wouldn't work on the object in its current form as it is `None` because of the OP's mistake. Which at this much deviation I think could use another answer.

Comment: @Nae: I really don't see the problem referring to calling `config` as "update the label's text" instead of "configure the label's text", but rather than argue, I've changed it. Meanwhile, the last paragraph already explains the problem with `cantidad` meaning `None`, so I'm not going to explain it in multiple places in the same answer. And finally, as I already explained, all of this is a side point to the OP's attempt to get `textvariable `working. An answer that said it's impossible and you must call `config` as your comment said would just be wrong.

Comment: @abarnert _"I really don't see the problem referring to calling config as "update the label's text" instead of "configure the label's text", but rather than argue, I've changed it."_ I was referring to the mistake you did on [the revision before last](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49184469/revisions). You can't use tkinter predefined `update` like that, it takes no arguments apart from its object, hence the example wouldn't work even if the object was a proper widget.

Comment: @Nae So you were referring to a mistake that I'd already corrected in the next revision, and you still feel the need to explain a mistake that I fixed before your comment? It seems to me like you're not actually trying to help anyone here, you're just looking for things to complain about. I believe this answer as it stands is useful to the OP, and to anyone else with a similar question; that's what matters here. If you disagree, I'm open to suggestions, but I don't want to debate whether previous versions were wrong for reason A or reason B.

Comment: @abarnert The mistake wasn't fixed at the time which I wrote [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184422/tkinter-not-showing-db-number-in-label/49184469?noredirect=1#comment85407347_49184469). You must have missed it, which does also explain your confusion about what it meant. I'm not looking for things to complain about, nor do you have to consider my comments as useful. I so believe the answer is (and was in it's all revisions) were helpful, I just wanted to make it so that it was without any flaws that I can see. Obviously you don't have to edit your post if you don't agree.

Comment: @Nae: So do you think the answer is now OK? Meanwhile, if you still think there should also be a different answer that convinces him not to use `textvariable` and jumps into the alternative, you should write it.